# Using input field with no Canvas, or finding any alternative

Tags: unity-game-engine

Im working on creating callendar to track progress on whatever tasks( like doing excercise etc) and one of features i want is possibility to add notes under each day.
To do it i need " input field " for user(simple strings).
Problem im facing is i do not want to use canvas and feature in Unity seem to work only with canvas.
When im adding " input field" component to game object nothing is showing up inside game.

Is there some extra step i need to do to use it on game object ?/ i cant use it without Canvas?
Perhaps there is alternative way of getting this effect i can't find.
I'd love a suggestion .

Answer (score 0):

You could probably go with TextMeshPro and colliders. There is a class called "RayCast" where it uses mouse input to shoot a ray in your 3D world. Put a collider on your text object and when that ray hits it you can detect that and act accordingly.